# Structured text(ST) programming PLC, debugging

Tags: debugging, plc, st

everyone. I have a question. So I am using OpenPCS and ST language. When I am compelled my program, the system did not detect any error, but I see that the program working not correct. Is it possible somehow to use "print" as in "python" or something like this to debug the soft?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the specific software, OpenPCS, but in general, to debug PLC software, they provide some tool to watch or spy variables. If they don't have such tool explicitly, you can still create helper variables and give them Modbus addresses so you can use an external Modbus Master program to read the variables and see their values so you can know how your application is executing.